# Is it possible to "vacuum form" a mesh onto another mesh?

Tags: topology, shrinkwrap

Suppose you have a mesh with X topology, it might be flat. You now want to "mold" that exact topology onto another mesh with a (maybe worse or somehow unfitting) topology. Shouldn't that be possible similar to cloth simulation? If yes, what approach would you use for this?

Think of vacuum forming of a plastic sheet over a mold see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_forming#/media/File:VacuformVisualization.gif

In contrast to vacuum forming and shrinkwrapping, it would be great, if one could define some important vertex of the target mesh, that supposed to be aligned exactly with certain vertex of the source mesh, so that certain features in the source mesh meet exactly with where the topology should appear on the target. Think like I can define sews for two cloth pieces where they should meet in the middle, but here they would not be on the edges of the flat pieces but in the middle of it so the selected vertex align exactly with the source, like corners of eyes or mouth, fingertips ect.

I seek to create an exact profile for a shell over another mesh.

Comment: I think that using the vertices and faces snapping options will let you do it as an easy task. Maybe also creating a copy of the target and start modeling from there.

Comment: [This paper](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00836048/file/ThA_se_MocanuBogdan.pdf) looks to be a good overview of feature-directed deformation.. '3D  Morphing' seems to be a good search-term.